# phonegap how to call jar method from js

Tags: android, cordova

Hi I am in mobile app.

I have developed an app in phonegap (html5, JQuery, JS) and I want to print a receipt to a bluetooth printer.

I purchase a BT printer, I download manufacturer's SDK and now I want to know the way that I have to follow in order to complete my app.

Printer Manufacturer SDK includes a .jar library that I can include into my project to expose printer manufacturers methods.

I follow all the steps to include the above .jar in my project.

Now I want to call a method from manufacturers .jar library from my app.

What is the correct way to do this.

Do I have to create a phoneGap plugin or is there any other way????

Is there any step by step tutorial???

thx in advance for your time

Answer (score 1):

There are really two parts to this question.

First you can create a phonegap plugin to interact with custom java code. In your case this would be "glue" for using the jar.

Second, you need to either add the jar to your project if it is available at compile time so that it gets included in the build, or if it is only available at run time (and contains compiled dex classes, rather than portable java ones) you load it with a dex class loader and call into it with reflection. But If it is a random jar for desktop use you eon't be able to use it.

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide